# Why does an async callback in for cycle only execute once?

Tags: javascript, typescript, selenium

I have a selenium-js function that takes callbacks

```
const poll = async <T extends error.WebDriverError>(
  action: Promise<void>,
  waitingAction: Promise<void>,
  errorConstructor: { new (): T },
): Promise<void> => {
  const maxIterations = 200
  for (let i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
    try {
      await action
      break
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof errorConstructor && i < maxIterations - 1) {
        await waitingAction
      } else throw e
    }
  }
}
```

What this should do, is to try `action`. If it fails with an expected error (still under maximum number of iterations), I perform a `waitingAction` and try again. In this case, `waitingAction` can be wait (for element to load), or scroll to an element.

However when I use function `scrollTo` as `waitingFunction`

```
const scrollTo = async (driver: Driver, selector: By) => {
  const element = await driver.findElement(selector)
  await driver.executeScript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView();', element)
}
```

it only executes once, even if the loop runs 200 times.

What gives? How can I ensure that the `waitingAction` is performed in each step?

Comment: Those aren't callbacks, those are promises. A promise only ever settles once. You haven't shown how you call `poll`, but basically you need to pass it functions, not promises, if you want the function to run repeatedly. E.g., you'd have `await action(/*...arguments here...*/)`, not `await action` and where you call it, pass in a function that returns a promise as `action`, rather than the result of calling the function.

Comment: Oh, that seems to be the problem :D I am still hazy on the proper nomenclature, thanks for clarifying. 

Changing `Promise<void>` to `() => Promise<void>` did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change your code to receive a delegate instead:

```
const poll = async <T extends error.WebDriverError>(
  action: () => Promise<void>,
  waitingAction: () => Promise<void>,
  errorConstructor: { new (): T },
): Promise<void> => {
  const maxIterations = 200
  for (let i = 0; i < maxIterations; i++) {
    try {
      await action(); // When we invoke the delegate we receive a new Promise each time.
      break
    } catch (e) {
      if (e instanceof errorConstructor && i < maxIterations - 1) {
        await waitingAction();
      } else throw e
    }
  }
}
```

and then call it like this:

```
await poll(() => myAction(), () => myWaitingAction(), myErrorCtor);
```